# Database design to support dynamic entities

Tags: sql-server, database-design

OK, I don't know whether this question belong to this place, but you will suggest me if I'm wrong.

I have some entities which has almost same attributes, differences is in maybe 2-3 columns.

Because of those different columns, I can't create one table with columns that are union of attributes of every entity, because new entity type will require changing table design adding new columns specific to that entity type.

Instead, currently working design is that every specific entity has own table.

But, if new type of entity come on scene, I must create new table, which is totally bad idea.

How can I create one table which consists shared attributes for each type of entity, and some additional mechanism to evidence entity-unique attributes?

So, idea is to easy add new types of objects, without changing database design, configuring only part that deal with unique columns.

P.S. Maybe I'm not clear, but I will add more description if is it needed.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or some other ORM?

Comment: Entity is term for record in table, in this situation

Comment: You should study up on "subclass" and ORM's.  That'll help you figure out what the options are, even if you "roll your own".    Here is a starter article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232034/Inheritance-mapping-strategies-in-Fluent-Nhibernat

Answer (score 2):

I had a design like that once. What I did was I created a table that housed all the shared properties. Then, I had separate tables for the distinct values. I used joins to match a specific entity to its shared table row. I had less than 10, so my views that used unions I just updated when I added a new entity. But, if you used a naming convention, you could write stored procs that find the table names dynamically and do the unions and joins on the fly. In my case, I used a base class and specific classes to make a custom data layer.

Another possibility is to have a generic table that's basically name/value pairs and a table the represents your shared properties. By joining the tables together, you could have any number of entity specific properties for your entities. It's not very efficient and the SQL would get weird, but I've seen it done.

Comment: OK, this is one approach, but when came new object, then I must change database design, and also, code to map those new tables.

Comment: That is true. I added another solution that I witnessed once that is more dynamic, but harder to implement.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to store the common parts in one table, and the specific parts in tables specific to that entity.

eg: To have a set of people, some of whom are managers...

Person Table

```
PersonID
PersonName
```

Manager Table

```
ManagerID
PersonID
DepartmentManaged
```

As soon as you go down the path of having one table with variable field meanings - effectively an Entity Attribute Value design - you find yourself in querying hell.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the best or most academic, but what about this kind of "open structure" ?

**MainTable**: all common fields

**SpecialProperties**: extra properties, as required
- MainRecordId  (P, F->MainTable)
- PropertyName  (P)
- PropertyText
- PropertyValue (for numeric values)